# Cannot globally install ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whatever I do, gem install is installing into my home, including /root/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems instead of /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0.

Some context :

```
# type gem
gem is hashed (/usr/bin/gem)

# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel),19(log)
```

Here is the exact command :

```
# /usr/bin/gem install --verbose --install-dir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0   aws-sdk
ERROR:  Use --install-dir or --user-install but not both
```

But from where come from this option : **--user-install**  ?

Nothing on the defaults options :

```
# gem install --help
Usage: gem install GEMNAME [GEMNAME ...] [options] -- --build-flags [options]
<...>
  Defaults:
    --both --version '>= 0' --document --no-force
    --install-dir /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0 --lock
```

What can I do to install in /usr/lib/ruby ?

Comment: *"Whatever I do"* ---- What **did** you do?!

Comment: I've put the exact command line with the result

Answer (score 1):

I've found the cause.
The global configuration /etc/gemrc

/etc/gemrc :

```
# Read about the gemrc format at http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

# --user-install is used to install to $HOME/.gem/ by default since we want to separate
#                pacman installed gems and gem installed gems
gem: --user-install
```